COMPLETED - Site maintenance - Wednesday, October 23, 2024, 9:00 PM-11:00 PM EDT (Thursday, October 24, 1:00 UTC - Thursday, October 24, 3:00 UTC)
[UPDATE 2 - Site maintenance has been completed]
[UPDATE - The maintenance window has been expanded by one hour in order to complete the planned updates and not postpone to later have yet another day of planned maintenance for this work. During the extended window, the site may go into read only for a brief period of time. I'll update this post when maintenance has been completed]
We have planned site maintenance that will briefly impact Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange users. The window is scheduled for Wednesday, October 23, 2024, 9:00 PM-10:00 PM EDT (Thursday, October 24, 1:00 UTC - Thursday, October 24, 2:00 UTC).
At some point during the maintenance window, the site will be read-only for approximately 15 minutes and portions of the site will be temporarily unavailable.
I'll update this post when the maintenance has been completed.

Just wondering, why does the site have maintenance/temporory outages this often?

Will this affect chat?

Seems to be read-only for short periods every 2 or 3 days for me. Business as usual.

"the site will be read-only" or "the site might be read-only"? (i.e. is the read-only actual and sure part of the maintenance?)

@Starship Various under-the-hood updates/changes to improve the performance/stability/upgradability of the site

@PM2Ring Yes, it will.

@W.O. That... should not be happening. Will you send an email to community-support@stackoverflow.com with any errors, patterns, sites it happens on, etc. so they can investigate?

@ShadowWizard Yes, it will be.

@W.O. see this. Answer there is pretty thorough and making lots of sense. (Its author worked for SE for a long time, so knows what he's talking about, it's not just a guess)

@Dalmarus Don't frequent outages to improve performance/stabilty count against performance/stability?

It has already been read-only for over 1h, and it's not even Thursday (UTC) yet.

Has the maintenance started prematurely or is there another issue? Site has been read-only for a couple of hours now!

I had an issue a couple of weeks ago where the site was in read-only for me but I couldn't find any evidence of issues. After a few days I cleared my SO cookies and that fixed it. Not sure how cookies play into read-only mode but if anyone's having issues, try clearing your cookies.

Yeah visiting https://stackoverflow.com/users/login for me shows "
Login is not available
The feature you’re trying to use is currently unavailable.
The site is currently in read-only mode. You can still access all the questions, answers, and general knowledge goodness.
We’ll enable all features of the site as soon as possible." Has been this way before the maintenance, and still is after it.

OK, so it's not just me: https://i.sstatic.net/2fkvLEPM.png

@Clonkex It's your cache. During times of maintenance, the team modifies the DNS entries to point the site to a failover datacenter which is always read-only. What happens is that your browser caches the DNS response from that time and fails to update it back once the maintenance is over.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog It wasn't regular page cache; I did ctrl+f5 a few times without success. Only clearing my cookies for the page worked. Perhaps if I had done Clear Host Cache at chrome://net-internals/#dns that may also have worked

Here's some more information on the long-term read-only issues folks are having, current work around, and in the comments, a link to the main post that I've added the status-reviewed tag and worked with the team to triage - no estimated timeframe of the fix, but the issue itself was discovered and confirmed, so that's a good start - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/403832/1189407
